# SPSS crosstabs and missing values

Tags: spss

I'm new in SPSS, I know how to do [crosstabs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqimlOU1KJs). But, I don't know how to include in the crosstabs analysis the missing values. Is someway to do it?

Is it possible to use multiple crosstabs like 2*3 or 3*4 ? How i can get relationship between two variable through crosstabs. Is it possible to find more feature1 vs feature2 vs feature3 relation through crosstabs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always check the [documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_crosstabs.htm) at first, more often than not you'll find the answer in there.

You can use the subcommand `MISSING=INCLUDE` which will include in the crosstab user defined missing values. If you have system missing values then only workaround is to temporarily recode them to a valid value.

```
TEMPORARY. 
RECODE V1 V2 (SYSMIS=-99).
CROSSTABS V1 BY V2.
```

The `TEMPORARY` command, as the name suggest, will temporarily recode the data by the transformations that proceed it until a procedure is run, in this case `CROSSTABS`. The data after the CROSSTABS is run would not have any of the transformations specified and so would be in its previous/original state.